# URL conversion (into link and urldecode)

Tags: php

I want to ask 2 questions about url conversion in php.

1 question: I need to convert text into link. I've done my own preg and also read many forums, but all solutions are connected with www. or (ht|f)tp(s), but I need preg that will convert domain names even without www and http in text, for example:

```
I like stackoverflow.com very much
```

into

```
I like <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>stackoverflow.com</a> very much
```

Sure it must consider points and commas and etc., like:

```
I like stackoverflow.com.
```

into

```
I like <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>stackoverflow.com</a>.
```

And one more question: links with url-encoded symbols on wiki are displayed as they are, but on other sites they are displayed like url-encoded string (%XX%XX%XX). How did wiki do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, I would not recommend you to that, it is very difficult to know if the a word containing a dot is a domain name or not, and people often forget to put a space after the dot in the middle of a paragraph.

for your second question, it is simple, you url encode the link in the href but not between the open and close a tag. For example :

```
<a href="http://site.na/test.php?t=sqdl%2654%22dfd%C2%B0%3D%2B">http://site.na/test.php?t=sqdl&54"dfd°=+</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. No, not link on the page. I said about link in address field in browser :) And do you know vk.com social network? Register and try their url conversion in privite messages, it's great, it's never makes a mistake.

Comment: you can use a list of domains (com / net / org ... etc) if it is after a dot then it is a link, but the list may be long

Comment: can you write me preg with .com for example? :)

Comment: something like this : `/\.(com|net|org|gov)\b/`

Answer (score 0):

The function `auto_link` from `CodeIgniter URL helper` can help you:

```
if ( ! function_exists('auto_link'))
{
    function auto_link($str, $type = 'both', $popup = FALSE)
    {
        if ($type != 'email')
        {
            if (preg_match_all("#(^|\s|\()((http(s?)://)|(www\.))(\w+[^\s\)\<]+)#i", $str, $matches))
            {
                $pop = ($popup == TRUE) ? " target=\"_blank\" " : "";

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches['0']); $i++)
                {
                    $period = '';
                    if (preg_match("|\.$|", $matches['6'][$i]))
                    {
                        $period = '.';
                        $matches['6'][$i] = substr($matches['6'][$i], 0, -1);
                    }

                    $str = str_replace($matches['0'][$i],
                                        $matches['1'][$i].'<a href="http'.
                                        $matches['4'][$i].'://'.
                                        $matches['5'][$i].
                                        $matches['6'][$i].'"'.$pop.'>http'.
                                        $matches['4'][$i].'://'.
                                        $matches['5'][$i].
                                        $matches['6'][$i].'</a>'.
                                        $period, $str);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($type != 'url')
        {
            if (preg_match_all("/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]*)/i", $str, $matches))
            {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches['0']); $i++)
                {
                    $period = '';
                    if (preg_match("|\.$|", $matches['3'][$i]))
                    {
                        $period = '.';
                        $matches['3'][$i] = substr($matches['3'][$i], 0, -1);
                    }

                    $str = str_replace($matches['0'][$i], safe_mailto($matches['1'][$i].'@'.$matches['2'][$i].'.'.$matches['3'][$i]).$period, $str);
                }
            }
        }

        return $str;
    }
}
```

Comment: this requires that the http/https or www exists